# How do you delete Survey123 attachments from a survey?

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service, attachments, land-survey, arcgis-survey123

There seems to be no documentation on how to delete Survey123 attachments. Is it actually feasible?

Is deleting the complete feature layer record required/necessary? (and if so, how can one be sure that the attachment was deleted, since the link to it was deleted?!)

Can the survey record be retained, but the attachment & relationship deleted?

Edit: My surveys and their attachements are stored in an ArcGIS Online Feature Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Esri github](https://github.com/Esri/Survey123Community/issues/433) community issue page, they have provided a way to do this:

> Once submitted, photos will be stored as geodatabase attachments, which can be deleted from the ArcGIS Online Map Viewer and ArcGIS Pro

[image]

Also, to add to this response, [Esri on it's survey123 help page](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/browser/create-surveys/faqcreatesurveys.htm#anchor17) or [update survey](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/browser/create-surveys/publishsurvey.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_97A01E11C37D401EB95C7D22EF251F66), does mention

> Can I modify an existing survey?
>   Before you publish a survey, you can modify the survey, such as changing the question label, adding questions, reordering questions, or deleting questions.
>
> Once a survey is published, you can make limited modifications to it. Edits that do not require changing the schema of the feature service can be made without issue.

Comment: you can delete GDB attachments in Catalog as well.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting attachments from a ArcGIS Online Feature Service that stores Survey123 features is feasible by interacting with the service URL. 
Carmel provided a working answer on Geonet, [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/195826-how-do-you-delete-survey123-attachments).